# URL masking? maybe?

Tags: asp.net, iis

Have a .net webapp running on IIS.

I have run across something I haven't had to really deal with before. we have partners or clients that have their own "pages" on our domain. currently the URL is www.mydomain.com/?code=partnercode, but for ease of use on business cards and such they want it to be more like www.mydomain.com/partnername and I am not sure how to do this.

I know we can do something like the following in the htaccess in Apache

```
RewriteRule ^partnername$ index.php?code=partnerid [L]
```

I am wondering if there is some way to do this in the web.config? there has got to be something, but I am unsure where to look to find it. I have tried those online htaccess to web.config code converters and it failed miserably. The other thing is I would prefer to not have to change the partnerID that we already have in the DB.

I found this on another question on this site but I don't think it will do what I need it to. It will change the URL in the browser one the user hits the page but I also want it to be accessible using the www.mydomain.com/partnername URL as well.

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/index.php?code=partnerid') {
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.history.pushState("", "", "/partnername");</script>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IIS has extension that partially supports your scenario, it is called [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

I said partially, because you can use it to rewrite URLs from `www.mydomain.com/partnername` to `www.mydomain.com/?code=partnername`. What it doesn't support (at least I don't think it does) is mapping a partner name to partner code (unless you have small number of partners and you can add rewrite rule for every partner).

And here is an article showing a [fraction of what you can do with URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module).

In your case if you want to rewrite `www.mydomain.com/partnername` to `www.mydomain.com/?code=partnername`, your rule configuration could look something like this (not tested on IIS):

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite to query string">
      <!-- I'm using hardcoded text, but it is regular expression and you can
           write very advanced conditions -->
      <match url="^(partner)" />
      <!-- changes incoming url /partner to ?code=partner -->
      <action type="Rewrite" url="?code={R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```